# $\tan^{-1}(x + 2) + \tan^{-1}(x) = \tan^{-1} (1/4)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $\tan^{-1}(x + 2) + \tan^{-1}(x) = \tan^{-1} (1/4)$.

I have tried using the inverse trigonometric tangent cancellation property.

Right now I have:

$\tan(tan^{-1}(x + 2)) + tan(\tan^{-1}(x)) = \tan(tan^{-1} (\frac{1}{4}))$

which is equivalent to

$x + 2 + x = \frac{1}{4}$.

However, I know that this cannot be right because there still needs to be a tangent to solve the equation properly and I know I need to apply the trigonometric sum of angles formula.

Comment: When you apply tangent to both sides, do you then immediately apply the sum/difference of angles formula for tangent?

Comment: We can't tell where you are having trouble if you only tell us vaguely what you are doing. Why not simply show all of your work?

Comment: Hint: let $\displaystyle \tan(a) = x+2, \tan(b) = x \implies \frac{1}{4} = \tan(a + b) = \frac{\tan(a) + \tan(b)}{1 - \tan(a)\tan(b)}.$  You end up with a quadratic equation in $x$.

Comment: By the way, re previous comment, I am assuming that $\tan^{-1}(r)$ is synonymous with arctan$(r)$.

Comment: Take the tangent of both sides and show your working.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for that helpful hint! So, when I use tan(a + b), that would mean I would have tan(2x + 2) correct?

Comment: @Jgastelum No.  Substitute $(x+2)$ for $\tan(a)$, $(x)$ for $\tan(b)$, and apply the exact formula that I gave for $\tan(a+b)$ in terms of $\tan(a)$ and $\tan(b)$.

Comment: @Jgastelum $(x+2)$ and $(x)$ are the **values** assigned to the tangent of the **angles** $(a)$ and $(b)$ respectively.  $(a)$ and $(b)$ are the angles.

Comment: So I am left with $x^2 + 6x +7 = 0$ and using the quadratic formula I have $-1 +/- \sqrt{2}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

$\tan(\theta) = \frac{O}{A} = \frac{x}{1}$, opposite = $x$, adjacent = $1$

Using pythag,

$H_1 = \sqrt{1 + x^2}, O_1 = x, A_1 = 1$

And

$\tan({\phi}) = \frac{O}{A} = \frac{x + 2}{1}$,

$H_2 = \sqrt{(x+2)^2 + 1}, O_2 = x+2, A_2 = A_1 = 1$

$\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{4})$,

$H_3 = \sqrt{17}, O_3 = 1, A_3 = 4$.

What's happening here is, just taking $\tan$ or $\tan^{-1}$ of the function may not be efficient. Instead lets take the $\cos$ of both sides. This way we can express them in terms of the ratios of the sides calculated above. Note how we are using $\cos$. We could use $\sin$, but honestly, the adjacents are the same ($= 1$) which makes life easier, in obtaining the answer.

So taking $\cos$ of both sides:

$$\cos(\tan^{-1}({x+2}) + \tan^{-1}({x}))) = \cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{4}))$$

And using our knowledge of $H_1, H_2, H_3$:

$$\cos(\tan^{-1}({x+2}) + \tan^{-1}({x}))) = \frac{A_3}{H_3}$$
$$\cos(\phi + \theta) = \frac{A_3}{H_3}$$
$$\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) - \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) = \frac{A_3}{H_3} \text{ 
(Expansion identity) }$$
$$\frac{A_2}{H_2} * \frac{A_1}{H_1} - \frac{O_2}{H_2} * \frac{O_1}{H_1} = \frac{A_3}{H_3}$$
$$\frac{A_2A_1 - O_2O_1}{H_1H_2}= \frac{A_3}{H_3}$$
$$\frac{1 - (x+2)(x)}{\sqrt{(1 + x^2)((x + 2)^2 + 1)}}= \frac{4}{\sqrt{17}}$$
Solve this for $x$ and you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $\arctan(x+2)+\arctan(x)=\arctan(\frac{1}{4})$.

We know, that $\bbox[lightgreen]{\tan\left(\arctan\left({x}\right)\right)=x}$, $\bbox[pink]{{x}\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$ and $\bbox[yellow]{\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}}$.

Therefore,
$$
\arctan(x+2)+\arctan(x)=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{4}\right),\iff
\\
\iff\tan(\arctan(x+2)+\arctan(x))=\tan\left(\arctan\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right),\iff
\\
\iff\frac{\tan(\arctan(x+2))+\tan(\arctan(x))}{1-\tan(\arctan(x+2))\cdot\tan(\arctan(x))}=\frac{1}{4},\iff
\\
\iff\frac{x+2+x}{1-x^{2}-2x}=\frac{1}{4},\iff\frac{2x+2}{-x^{2}-2x+1}=\frac{1}{4},\iff
\\
\iff\frac{8x+8+x^{2}+2x-1}{-4(x^{2}+2x-1)}=0,\iff\frac{x^{2}+10x+7}{-4(x^{2}+2x-1)}=0,\iff
\\
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
x^{2}+10x+7=0,\\
x^{2}+2x-1\ne{0}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
\iff
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
x=-5\pm{3\sqrt{2}},\\
x\ne{-1\pm{\sqrt{2}}}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Here is the answer:
$$
\bbox[lightblue]
{
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
x=-5\pm{3\sqrt{2}},\\
x\ne{-1\pm{\sqrt{2}}}.\\
\end{array}
\right.
}
$$